# mysql_xdevapi php: connection was reset error

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE: It's logging this error on the apache error log: AH00428: Parent: child process 27612 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.

The mysql_xdevapi session appears to be working fine at first, but breaks when I try to perform multiple operations, close it and open another session, or even when using it in a singleton class and getting the existing instance.

This code below throws the same error. There are no errors on the logs, it just says on the browser that the connection was reset.

```
<?php
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$host = '127.0.0.1';

$session = mysql_xdevapi\getSession("mysqlx://{$username}:{$password}@{$host}");
$schema = $session->getSchema('test');
$collection = $schema->getCollection('users');
$result = $collection->find('email = :email')->bind(['email' => 'test@email'])->limit(1)->execute();
$result = $result->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
$session->close();

$session2 = mysql_xdevapi\getSession("mysqlx://{$username}:{$password}@{$host}");
$schema2 = $session2->getSchema('test');
$collection2 = $schema2->getCollection('users');
$result2 = $collection2->find('email = :email')->bind(['email' => 'test@email'])->limit(1)->execute();
$result2 = $result2->fetchAll();
print_r($result2);
$session2->close();
```

I’m currently using PHP 8.0.29, MySQL 8.0.28, mysql_xdevapi 8.0.28.
I tried with different versions of PHP (that mysql_xdevapi works with) and it’s the same.

I’ve looked at MySQL max number of connections and memory usage and they are fine.

If you know any combination of PHP/MySQL versions that this works on, that would also be sufficient.